# PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager Not Responding

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to create a PostGIS connection with PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager, but each time I try to do this the application stops responding.

This is what is written in my Log Window (except the password which I redacted).

```
Connecting: host=localhost port=5050 user=postgre
password='REDACTED' dbname=sdb_course client_encoding=UTF8
```

This is the version of the application I have downloaded:

PostGIS Bundle 3 for PostgreSQL x64 16 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter

Version of PostgreSQL : 16

Why is this happening? I understand this is a broad question to ask, but I'm not sure where to start unpacking this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Start the process, let it hang, connect to the database from psql/pgadmin/another client and `select * from pg_stat_activity;` My bet is that it's working fine, but if your shapefile is sufficiently large and complex, and/or disk, memory, network resources are a bottleneck, it'll just take some time for the file to load. Some apps don't do progress bars too well, or not at all, and let the system assume they're passively unresponsive when they're busy. The query above will tell you what all db clients are doing, and something along the lines of `COPY FROM stdin` should be in the `query` column

Comment: It's also possible you'll see that the query issued by the loader app is blocked by something, e.g. if it tries to drop+recreate/wipe+repopulate/rename/alter the table while something else is still using it. There's a [lock monitoring page on the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) where you can find a query that will let you see what's blocking what. You'll need to ask whoever blocks that to finish their work, or `select pg_cancel_backend(pid);` or even `select pg_terminate_backend(pid);` if you don't mind simply shutting them down.